# Can't get a input focus parent in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I not able to get the parent of the form group when I focus on a input inside this group? On input focus I am getting an object in Firefox returned in the console: Object { length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: , 1 more… } however, this is not the object I am interested in. Both this and .parent() are returning the same HTML node. I am using the `console.log($(this).parent());` code inside of the inputFocus method.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group repeat-group" id="something" data-num="1">
  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 ">
  <input type="text" id="description" name="desc" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var formAutoGenerator = function() {
    var self = this; //$ has it's own 'this'
    this.repeatGroup = $('.repeat-group');
    this.formGroupLength = this.repeatGroup.length;
    this.init = function(){
        this.inputFocus(); 
        this.correctClassAdded();
    };
    this.classTag = 'repeat-group'; 
    this.correctClassAdded = function(formGroup){
       // console.log( $(formGroup).offsetParent() );
        return formGroup; 
    };
    this.inputFocus = function() {
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.repeat-group input').on('focus', function(e) {
                if ( self.correctClassAdded( $(this) ) ) {
                    console.log('working');

                } 
                console.log($(this).parent());
            var group = $(this).parent().siblings().children();
            var groupInputValArray = []; 
            var emptyCounter = 0; 
            for ( a = 0; a <= group.length -1; a++){
                //if the input does not have a value add null
                if ( group[a].value === ""){ emptyCounter++; }
                groupInputValArray.push(group[a].value);
            }
            //if the array contains only one null then add another form group
            if ( emptyCounter == 1){
                //then we will go ahead and add our new group
            }
               }); 
        });
    }
    this.appendGroup = function(){

    }; 
    this.init(); 
}

var newfields = new formAutoGenerator();
```

Comment: What are you trying mixing vanilla JS and jQuery? `$(document).ready(function(){` inside an event handler? Seriously?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` only fires once when the page loads -- that should in the global document scope not within another function

Comment: @PraveenKumar - nothing wrong with mixing vanilla JS and jQuery . . . just not like that.   ;)

Comment: console.log(this.parentNode); should give you what you want, but you have deeper issues here...

Answer (score 0):

it's retrieving an object of the node you are trying to get.

You have one of two options:

1. do `$(this).parent()[0];` to get the div parent node
2. or `this.parentNode;`

Comment: ITYM `this.parentNode()`, since it's a DOM method.

Comment: @akiespenc Not sure: `$(this).parentNode();` might work. You should do `thisparentNode;`

Comment: #1 should be `$(this).parent()[0]`; no reason to make the index a string when it will just be coerced back to a number. #2, to correct what @Barmar mentioned, should be `this.parentNode`, as [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) is not a function. Feel free to [edit] your answer to change your answer to use the correct syntax.